# Trying to use a ping tool package in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, ping

Laravel Framework 5.8.31
NPM 6.4.1
Node v8.16.0

Im need to run ICMP pings in my laravel project.

Im trying to use packages like ping https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping or net-ping https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping

Installed them running:
npm install ping
npm install net-ping

Then edited bootstrap.js:

var Ping = require('ping');
var NetPing = require('net-ping');

And...

npm run dev

ping error

```
This dependency was not found:
* child_process in ./node_modules/ping/lib/ping-promise.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/ping/lib/ping-promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/var/www/html/laravel/ipam/node_modules/ping/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ping/lib/ping-promise.js 15:9-33
 @ ./node_modules/ping/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Install child-process  (+ child_process@1.0.2) but no luck

Error for net-ping (it uses raw-socket)

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-socket/build/Release/raw.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/raw-socket/index.js 4:10-46
 @ ./node_modules/net-ping/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

I've been trying to find a solution but no luck.

Comment: what is your node version ?

Comment: Node version v8.16.0

Comment: By running directly using node, it works:

ping.js:

var ping = require('ping');
 
var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

$ node resources/js/ping.js
host google.com is alive
host yahoo.com is alive
host 192.168.1.1 is dead